# create new objects in http get map

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript

I have a function that subscribes to a search api. In the map function I would like to map the items to objects. I do not get an error but the response is always empty.

this is my code:

```
return this.http.get(searchURL)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .map(json => json.items.forEach(item => {
      new SearchResult(
          item.id,
          item.title,
          item.price
      );
  }) || []);
```

Comment: what's with the || [] at the end there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **map** over the returned list and transform it instead of **forEach**.

Also, if the list of items is empty **map** will return an empty list, you don't need to do the || [] anymore.

```js
return this.http.get(searchURL)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .map(json => json.items.map(item => {
    return new SearchResult(
      item.id,
      item.title,
      item.price
    );
  }));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return from it:

```
return this.http.get(searchURL)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .map(json => json.items.map(item => {
    return new SearchResult(
      item.id,
      item.title,
      item.price
    );
  }))
  .catch((err: Response) => { 
    // handle error
  })
```

`forEach` doesn't return anything, while `map` produces new array with items which you return from callback.

Also, note that `|| []` check is useless. If `json.items` is an array then map will always produce another array. If it's not an array then it will throw error, which you need to handle with `.catch` block attached after your `.map` (Obeservable map I mean).

Comment: thank you very much, but toskv was a littel bit faster

Comment: @TobiasEtter Haha, actually I was 1 minute faster, but whatever ;)